# WinVista and Chrome freezing on high disk usage

Tags: hard-drive, google-chrome, windows-vista, ntfs, freeze

I'm trying to diagnose an issue with my PC.  I see unresponsive apps like chrome and windows explorer. The UI is responsive but its still very annoying.  THe HD utilization seems high when this happens.  When I look at the performance monitor, I see the most writing to the pagefile and NTFS volume log and NTFS master file table. I also see memory hard faults intermittently peak to 150/sec. The HP diagnostic utility doesn't show issues with my hardware. I have no idea how to fix or diagnose further. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @gronostaj I have 8gb of ram.